# API requests with authentication: Python's requests vs. R's httr

Tags: python, r, python-requests, httr

I'm new to API's.  I want to access an API, with authentication, using R's `httr` library but I keep getting a not authorized status.

A colleague gave me some code using Python's `requests` library which works great.  However, I haven't had much success trying to replicate it using R's `httr` library. Looking around online, and through the `httr` documentation, I thought this should be quite easy using the `GET()` function but it gives me the `401 (NotAuthorised)` status. Now I'm not even sure if I should be using `GET()` or `PUT()` as was used with Python's requests.

Python example (works fine):

```
import requests

IM_id = "aUser"
IM_pass = "aPassword"
DataAccess ={"username":IM_id,"password":IM_pass}
URL = 'https://io.aWebsite.live/integrate/1/session'

p = requests.put(URL,DataAccess)
p

<Response [200]>

IMkey = p.json()
print('your API token is ' + IMkey['apiToken'])

your API token is xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxx-xxxx
```

R example (error):

```
library(httr)

IM_id <- "aUser"
IM_pass <- "aPassword"
URL <- "https://io.aWebsite.live/integrate/1/session"

r <- GET(URL,authenticate(IM_id,IM_pass,type="basic"))

r

Response [https://io.aWebsite.live/integrate/1/session]
  Date: 2019-06-29 23:12
  Status: 401
  Content-Type: <unknown>
<EMPTY BODY>
```

Comment: what happens when using PUT? Have you also checked what the default content type is in both requests PUT and httr PUT?

Comment: @QHarr,
If I replace `GET()` with `PUT()` I get a 400 status,

```
Response [https://io.aWebsite.live/integrate/1/session]
  Status: 400
  Content-Type: <unknown>
<BINARY BODY>
```

If I remove `/session` from `URL` I get a 404 status and the content 
type says `application/json; charset=utf-8` so I assume this is the default content?

```
Response [https://io.aWebsite.live/integrate/1]
  Status: 404
  Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
```

As I understand the initial call is the open a session and obtain the apiToken